# 2001 Infiniti car-oil doesn’t leak park on incline

Tags: oil-leak, infiniti, q30

I had some oil leaks fixed on my car the gasket and oil was leaking on spark plug so I got that fix.  Now I only have a small leak when I park in my driveway on flat surface.   But when I park on incline nose up I don’t have any oil leaking.  Can someone help explain why?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the model and engine of your Infiniti? Where exactly is it still leaking from?

Comment: 2001 Infiniti Q30 3.0 V6

Answer (score 0):

Probably a leak in the oil pan gasket near the front of the pan.

When the car is level, the oil level is high enough near the front of the pan for the oil to leak out. When the car is parked nose up, the oil runs to the back of the pan and can no longer escape where the leak is.

If you were to take a look underneath (probably have to remove a bunch of plastic vanity/aerodynamic panels from the under side), you'd see the drips near the front of the pan.